# Can't figure out how to use arguments for my function

Tags: c#, winforms

I am currently doing a small program that consist to help me understand functions and C# overall. However, I can't find how to use my function.

I'll give you a simple example from the code I built :

```
int[] monTab = { 20, 56, 42, 5, 100, 123, 500 };    

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Here I want to use the afficherTab(int[] x)
    //Code I thought :
    afficherTab(x);
}

public void afficherTab(int[] x)
{
    textBox1.Text = monTab[0].ToString(); 
    textBox2.Text = monTab[1].ToString(); 
    textBox3.Text = monTab[2].ToString();
    textBox4.Text = monTab[3].ToString();
    textBox5.Text = monTab[4].ToString(); 
    textBox6.Text = monTab[5].ToString(); 
    textBox7.Text = monTab[6].ToString();
}
```

As you can see it's pretty simple, I just really wonder how to make my text box work at this point if I use them on the `Form1_Load` function.

NOTE : It's only showing a list of 7 boxes so far, I'll add stuff to it later on. I need to understand how to do that first to continue though.

Comment: `afficherTab` expects a parameter of type `int[]`, what is `x`? But, more generally what is your error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to pass your array `monTab` to your function from `Form_Load` event. `X` is the name of the parameter and that is local to your function, it is not available in your `Form_Load` event.

```
afficherTab(monTab);
```

With your current code, since you have defined `monTab` at class level you don't have to pass that to your function, you can access it directly in your method.

You can also use [named parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx) like:

```
afficherTab(x: monTab);
```

Comment: Damn, thanks for the explaination, I feel kind of dumb now haha.

Seriously TY! It worked perfectly and I now understand that thing :)!

Comment: @user3078728, glad to be a help, don't worry , we all started from somewhere.